# Single quote inside of double quoted string on linux command line

Tags: linux, shell, escaping

I have the following command

```
cmd '"asdf" "a'sdf"'
```

I need to surround the arguments with single quotes only. cmd doesnt work with double quotes for some reason I dont know. The above command doesnt work because the single in the middle terminates the first single quote. If I escape, to the following

```
cmd '"asdf" "a\'sdf"'
```

It still doesnt work. How do I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the bash man page:

```
   Enclosing  characters in single quotes preserves the literal value
   of each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur
   between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
```

So the answer is, you can't include a single quote within a single-quoted string no matter how you try. But depending on how your script is set up you may be able to use `'\''`, which will end the first single quote, escape the second, and start another single-quoted string with the third.

Answer (score 1):

A long long time ago, a mentor suggested I use constructs like `'"asdf" "a'"'"'sdf"'`.  It works, but it's bizarre to look at.

Since you can't put single quotes inside single quotes, escaping them like `'"asdf" "a'\''sdf'` may be the way to go.

Note that you can also use `printf` and variables interactively or within a shell script.  With most shells (you haven't specified what you're using), you should get the similar results to this:

```
$ fmt='"asdf" "a%ssdf"\n'
$ printf "$fmt" "'"
"asdf" "a'sdf"
$
```

or you could even include the single quote using its ASCII value:

```
$ fmt='"asdf" "a\047sdf"\n'
$ printf "$fmt"
"asdf" "a'sdf"
$
```

or in csh:

```
% set fmt='"asdf" "a\047sdf"\n'
% printf "$fmt"
"asdf" "a'sdf"
%
```

This is shell-independent because if your shell doesn't have a `printf` command built in (as Bash has), then the command will most likely exist as a separate binary in /bin or /usr/bin.

I don't know your use case, so it's difficult to come up with a solution that I know will be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always use autocomplete to help you find the answer.

For instance, if I have a file with an apostrophe in it, but I want to surround the path with single quotes, I can do this (using `cat` as an example command where the file is named `sam's file.txt`):

```
cat 'sam[press tab here]
```

and it autocompletes to this, for me:

```
cat 'sam'\''s\ file.txt
```

So, apparently it is possible. Another answerer mentioned the `'\''` thing first, but I figured I'd tell you one way to try to figure it out if that's not working for you (and I thought I'd be another witness to tell you the other answer seems to work).